# Update dynamic object

Tags: javascript

I have an object :

```
{ 
    ...,
    values: {},
    ...
}
```

`values` is empty by default.

Now I want to add dynamic object to this object :

```
[myDynamicProperty]: {
     title: '...',
     introduction: '...'
}
```

That's ok, I know how to do this. But, on other action, I have to add `key: value` or `key: object` to `[myDynamicProperty]`, when I try something, I loose the values of my `[myDynamicProperty]`

I've tried to clone my initial object, but it doesn't work.

For sure, someone on stackoverflow has the solution.

Comment: If you share more details of your specific case, maybe we can help :-)

Comment: Can you please show what the code that makes you lose the values?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having; adding properties to an object doesn't delete existing one. Are you sure you're not setting the entire property?

Comment: `obj.values[myDynamicProperty].key = value;`

Comment: I have a feeling you did something like values.myDynamicProperty = {foo: 'bar'}, when it should values.myDynamicProperty.foo = 'bar'

Comment: @CharlieNg Actually, it would be `values[myDynamicProperty]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a two step approach by assigning a default object to `myDynamicProperty` and then assign the values to it.

This keeps all properties of `object.values[myDynamicProperty]` and changes only the given keys.

```
var object = {
        values: {},
    }

object.values[myDynamicProperty] = object.values[myDynamicProperty] || {};
Object.assign(object.values[myDynamicProperty], { title: '...', introduction: '...' });
```

Comment: Actually in my code I've used `let newValues = Object.assign(object.values[myDynamicProperty], ...);` But It doesn't work like this, I don't understand why. Thank you for your quick help.

Comment: please add the dynamic property to the question, not just a structure, but some real data for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convey that you are starting with an object such as:

```
var user = {
  meta: {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Smith"
  }
}
```

and wish to add `middle_name` to the `meta` object property, then you should do the following.

`Object.assign(user['meta'], {middle_name: "Harry"});`

Note that the first object will be overwritten with values from the later object(s). The later object properties will take precedence over previous objects properties. See [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for further details. **WARNING**: This is an ES6 feature, use a polyfill for backwards compatibility if necessary.